# Retrieve every key of a column family in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I have found no way to translate a simple select like `SELECT * FROM USER` into Cassandra. Is it possible to simply retrieve all the keys in a ColumnFamily? The only one I have found is a select with a key range (`get_range_slices`). Is there a way to get the entire key list without the need to define a key range?

Thanks
Tobia Loschiavo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use get_range_slices, start with "", and after each call use the last key as the start key in the next call

Comment: Would you please provide an example for the same?